# order of elements in Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

The `Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll(System.Threading.Tasks.Task[] tasks, Action<System.Threading.Tasks.Task[]> continuationAction)` [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskfactory.continuewhenall?view=net-5.0#System_Threading_Tasks_TaskFactory_ContinueWhenAll_System_Threading_Tasks_Task___System_Action_System_Threading_Tasks_Task____) does not state that the order of elements in the `continuationAction` will be identical and correspond to the order of elements in the `tasks` input parameter. Is it possible to prove/refute this (besides looking at empirical results)?

Comment: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/tasks/FutureFactory.cs,ca53c3b1e37aa2e9

Comment: Documentation can lie or quickly become outdated. Source code can be misunderstand quite easily because of the its complexity. Experiments can prove or refute your thesis. BTW, yes it will preserve the ordering.

Comment: @user80 What exactly are you looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is *implementation detail*, which is subject to changes.  Whatever you prove / refute, it will be per specific version of .Net and on certain hardware.  There is no guarantee the order might not change in future, or even on a different platform.  If the order is not documented, you must not assume any.  Much better make sure you can identify your tasks and sort based on that identity for your purposes.

Comment: Nick - that is what I thought also, since sort order is not explicitly in the spec best not rely on it. Thanks.